# How can I remove children pages that I added to my main() method?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have an application that has tabbed pages:

```
public partial class MainPage : TabbedPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        App.cardsPage = new Cards();
        App.homePage = new HomePage();
        App.helpPage = new HelpPage();
        App.settingsPage = new SettingsPage();
        App.phrasesPage = new PhrasesFrame();
    }
```

I add these pages like this:

```
    Children.Add(App.navHomePage);
    Children.Add(App.navHelpPage);
    Children.Add(App.navSettingsPage);
    Children.Add(App.navCardsPage);
    Children.Add(App.navPhrasesFrame);
```

Can someone tell me how for example I can remove the navHelpPage and the navCardsPage and then how can I add it back (in the same order) later?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you can do.

to remove :

```
Children.Remove(navHelpPage)
```

To add it back again at position 1 (starts at 0)

```
Children.Insert(1, navHelpPage);
```